# Send Multiple values as a parameter using SOAP in android?

Tags: android

Can some body please guide me on this.I am totally new to using KSOAP in android.Following are my details in XML.And i want to Send the details in webservice.Please tell me how to addProperty am i doing something wrong there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckLoginWithIPhoneData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Pin>string</Pin>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <DeviceID>string</DeviceID>
    </CheckLoginWithIPhoneData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And in java code I have done this:

```
public void showdetails() 
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

        request.addProperty("UserName","sometext");
        request.addProperty("Pin","sometext");
        request.addProperty("Password","sometext");
        request.addProperty("DeviceID","sometext");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
            Log.e("RESPONSE",""+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.e("result",""+result);

            if (result != null)

            {
                Log.e("val", "" + result.getProperty(0).toString());
            }

            else

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

I have called the method in background.

However I get the following error when i try to print the RESPONSE
Log.e("RESPONSE",""+androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>`
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://tempuri.org/CheckLoginWithIPhoneData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        request = new SoapObject(Util.getInstance().NAMESPACE, method);

    AuthenticateRequest authenticateRequest = (AuthenticateRequest) params[0];

    SoapObject authenticate = new SoapObject(Util.getInstance().NAMESPACE, "CheckLoginWithIPhoneData");

    authenticate.addProperty("UserName", <value>);
    authenticate.addProperty("Pin", <value>);
    authenticate.addProperty("Password", <value>);
    authenticate.addProperty("DeviceID", <value>);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
    propertyInfo1.namespace = Util.getInstance().NAMESPACE;
    propertyInfo1.name = "CheckLoginWithIPhoneData";

    request.addProperty(propertyInfo1, authenticate);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have the Variables related to SOAP request as Below :

Generally the `SOAP_ACTION` Should be Combination of `NAMESPACE` and `METHOD_NAME`

> **SOAP_ACTION=NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME**

Sample values of Above Variables :

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://uri.org/GetFormData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetFormData";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://uri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://inukshk.com/getformsdata/sample.asmx";
```

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

The type of String that you wrote might be incorrect, for example for "Pin" tag if it only accepts integer and if you write char it gives you an error.